# Keep sourced file after script execution

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to keep source from an executed script  without sourcing it ?

Here is the script `install.sh`:

```
JJJ=bar
```

When i execute the script like `./install.sh`, after execution, i got the following prompt `JJJ` :

> user1@localhost% echo $JJJ

When i source the file, like `source install.sh`, i got the following value for `$FOO` :

> user1@localhost% echo $JJJ
>   bar

For, now all is ok.

But i would like to know if there is a way to set the JJJ value and keep the value of JJJ after script execution, without sourcing the script.
In other words, is a their a way that after `./install.sh`, the following prompts gives :

> user1@localhost% echo $JJJ
>   bar

Comment: Look in that script for where it sets `PS1`, which is where your prompt is defined, and incorporate it in your own which is usually set in your `profile`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Just setting the prompt won't activate a virtualenv...

Comment: **Why** do you want to run rather than source?

Comment: @l0b0 Hi, this example is just a simple example. The real probleme is that i execute a script that inside is sourcing another script. I would like that this source stay persistent. In the executed script, the command source virtualenv/bin/activate is triggered, and i would like to keep this source persistent. Is it possible ?

Comment: If you source the top level script, and that sources `virtualenv/bin/activate`, you're golden.

Comment: @l0b0 Ok, i was wondering if there was a way without sourcing the top level script, using set command line for example or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i). The selected answer is very thorough. To allow the variable to persist, you'll need to use the `export` function as your current deceleration is limited to the context of the script.

Change `install.sh` to:

`export FOO=BAR`

Then instead of `./install.sh` you could try `. install.sh`

Comment: `source` and `.` are equivalent.

Comment: @Crypteya Thanks for link, it gives more clues. The real probleme is that i execute a script that inside source another script. I would like that this source stay persistent. In the executed script, the command source virtualenv/bin/activate is triggered, and i would like to keep this source persistent. Is it possible ?